# Grails-SpringSec depends on JARs that aren't in Maven Central?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-security-cas

I am trying to configure a Grails app to use the latest stable [SpringSec-CAS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas) and for the life of me cannot find the proper version of both SpringSec and the plugin I should be using.

I am on Grails 2.3.6. What should I include in `BuildConfig.groovy` to get the latest **stable** versions?  I have:

```
plugins {
    compile  ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
    compile  ":spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1"
}
```

When I specify SpringSec 2.0-RC2 and SpringSec-CAS 2.0-RC1 I get the following errors when running `grails run-app`:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in mylocalartifactory_artifactory_libs-snapshots-local_ (http://mylocalartifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local/) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in mylocalartifactory_artifactory_libs-snapshots-local_ (http://mylocalartifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local/) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in mylocalartifactory_artifactory_libs-snapshots-local_ (http://mylocalartifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local/) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in mylocalartifactory_artifactory_libs-snapshots-local_ (http://mylocalartifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local/)
```

I take it that I don't have my repositories set up correctly...? How can I modify my `BuildConfig.groovy` to pull these deps in from Maven Central?

Running Grails dependency report:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC2
|    >>>> org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.RC1
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1
|    \--- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:3.2.1
|    >>>> org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:3.2.0.RC1
```

Still not 100% sure what the problem is.

Comment: Latest version of [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) is 2.0-RC2 and that of [Spring Security cas](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas) is 2.0-RC1. I know the latest version of SSC is used widely. Do you face any problem using them?

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - please see my error above.

Comment: Do you have `mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"` added to BuildConfig as mentioned in both of the plugins?

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - no I don't but will try it. Just out of curiosity, why aren't these in `mavenCentral`? If its because they are RCs ("bleeding edge"), then I'm simply looking for the latest version of them that *would* be in `mavenCentral`. Thanks again!

Comment: And to answer your question @dmahapatro, **no**, adding your `mavenRepo` config didn't fix the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding  mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/" resolved the dependency issue for me.